# split function for splitting with unicode character

Tags: python, regex

I m not able to split unicode character \u2013 in the below code

```
actualdata=metatry['content'].split("-")
print "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+actualdata[0]
dat=actualdata[0].split("\u2013")
print "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+dat[0]
productlist.append(dat[0])
```

Output does not get rid of \u2013 even if its present
Would be helpful if someone helped me on this.

Comment: Could you provide `metatry['content']` value?

Comment: "Samsung Galaxy Note II \u2013 Latest Smartphone in India "

Comment: @root: i m using beautiful soup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `'u'` to the `'\u2013'` as `metatry['content']` is a unicode string:

```
u"Samsung Galaxy Note II \u2013 Latest Smartphone in India ".split(u'\u2013')
```

Comment: IT worked.Thanks for such quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

`metatry['content']` is a [unicode object](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings), not a string. So your `split` call fails:

```
>>> s = u"Samsung Galaxy Note II \u2013 Latest Smartphone in India "
>>> s.split("\u2013")
[u'Samsung Galaxy Note II \u2013 Latest Smartphone in India ']
```

You have to split it with the *unicode* charater `\u2013` instead:

```
>>> s = u"Samsung Galaxy Note II \u2013 Latest Smartphone in India "
>>> s.split(u"\u2013")
[u'Samsung Galaxy Note II ', u' Latest Smartphone in India ']
```

---

PS: You said you work with Beautiful Soup. [Beautiful Soup uses unicode strings only](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit).